# The effect of temperature on different substances

Tags: temperature, atoms

The change of temperature causes the atoms and more specifically nucleons and electrons to move. When they move, intermolecular distance between the molecules changes and so the state of matter changes( for example from gas to liquid) 
As all kinds of substances are made of atoms and so of electrons and nucleons , then the effect of change of temperature (for example: difference of boiling point) is due to the difference of number of electrons and nucleons since it has to do with the collisions between the particles. 
Am I thinking right??

Comment: The question is unclear to me.

Comment: I'm asking whether what I've said is true or not . The way I'm thinking.

Comment: temperature is a thermodynamic  variable and does not know about electrons and nuclei. It knows whole atoms which can have degrees of freedom ,  in a solid within a lattice there are vibrational and rotational degrees of freedom. In gases and liquids there are also translational  degrees of freedom. Temperature is related to kinetic energy . http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temperp.html